# Unknown character encoding for zip file in archive manager

Tags: tar, zip, character-encoding, archive

Forenote: I am quite new to Linux, and am really just a beginner.

I have downloaded a zip file from a respectable-looking site with firefox; it should contain stuff to install an application.
The zip file is called: `/tmp/mozilla_martin0/gdevelop-5.0.0-beta83.tar.gz`.

The archive manager has struck a pause and tells me that xed could not detect the character encoding. I have looked it up and now have a decent novice idea of what character encoding is.

It asks me to check that I am not trying to open a binary file, and then asks me to select a character encoding from the menu and try again. The menu shows: Current Locale (UTF-8); Western (ISO-8859-15);
Add or Remove...

The set setting is to automatically detect the character encoding.

My question: what should a new fellow like me do to install this program and avoid making a problem.

Footnote: OS is Linux Mint 19.1 Cinnamon; Cinnamon version is 4.0.10; L. Kernel is 4.15.0-70-generic. (I simply do not really know what more info people will actually need in order to help; I have done as I have thought best)

Comment: You should unzip with a program that does not try to interpret what it is un-zipping. (archiving tools have no business changing what they are archiving/de-archiving)

Comment: I don't think zip program has problems with your encoding. It says that xed could not detect the character encoding. I think xed is an editor that tries to open a file which you file managers unzips to some temporary location. I would recommend to unzip files first (https://askubuntu.com/questions/25347/what-command-do-i-need-to-unzip-extract-a-tar-gz-file) and then open them with whatever editor you want.

Comment: Your question does not esplain your problem. You did not mention the program you are using and you did not explain the error you had.